# Copy the image from one folder to another in Gallery

Tags: android, copy

In my app i want to pick the image from gallery and display the image in ImageView and also want to move the image to new folder. I got image in ImageView but it is does't move to another folder. Can any one help me?
I used bellow code to achieve this....

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

        }
    });
```

In onActivityResult

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        System.out.println("File Path Column "+filePathColumn);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        System.out.println("Column Index "+columnIndex);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
        Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
        System.out.println("Image patha in Messaging "+picturePath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(preview_bitmap);
        differentpic.setText("Click on Upload if you wish to solve a different pic");
        differentpic.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 30);

        OutputStream out;
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Solve");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Solve"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+"jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
        file.createNewFile();
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);                       
        //Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
        //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int bytes = preview_bitmap.getByteCount();
      //or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
      //int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4; 

      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
      preview_bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

      byte[] array = buffer.array();


            out.write(array);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // TODO Auto-generated catch block


    }

 }
```

What i did wrongly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

If you have path of both files sourceFile and destinationFile then you can copy file using following code.

```
/**
 * copies content from source file to destination file
 * 
 * @param sourceFile
 * @param destFile
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: i know the destination but i dont know the source... it may be any folder

Comment: yes...but you will get path of selected file in onActivityResult()

Comment: @KetanAhir, I am trying to get path of selected file in onActivityResult(), but it is giving me NullPointerException. Need help please.       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download/2015-09-09.jpg flg=0x1 }} to activity {Package name}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference

Comment: @KetanAhir, I am trying to get path of selected file in onActivityResult(), but it is giving me NullPointerException. Need help please. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download/20‌​15-09-09.jpg flg=0x1 }} to activity {Package name}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference `

Comment: If you are using the path instead of File then make sure to convert your path into the File type first and then execute the above code. It will work fine)))

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code

```
 private OnClickListener photoAlbumListener = new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sharedresources/"+HelperFunctions.getDateTimeForFileName()+".png";
        uriImagePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagepath));
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriImagePath);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY);

      }
  };






  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch(requestCode){


             case 22:
                    Log.d("onActivityResult","uriImagePath Gallary :"+data.getData().toString());
                    Intent intentGallary = new Intent(mContext, ShareInfoActivity.class);
                    intentGallary.putExtra(IMAGE_DATA, uriImagePath);
                    intentGallary.putExtra(TYPE, "photo");
                    File f = new File(imagepath);
                    if (!f.exists())
                    {
                        try {
                            f.createNewFile();
                            copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())), f);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    startActivity(intentGallary);
                    finish();
             break;


            }
          }





    }

   private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
            FileChannel destination = null;
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            if (destination != null && source != null) {
                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            }
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }


}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

   String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
   int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: sorry i cant able to understand onActivityResult().. can u explain me